# .filter command not working for my .plist in swift

Tags: swift

So my code below is being used to try and filter out just the names from the array of dictionaries I have created. I was given a lot of advice in a previous question but now I face a new problem. I can't actually implement the .filter function. I have tried it in many different methods but I am left with the code you see below. Any advice on what I could be missing would be appreciated! I get the error message that the cardArray does not have a member named 'filter'.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("CardList", ofType: "plist")
    let plistDict = NSDictionary(contentsOfFile: "/path") as! Dictionary<String,AnyObject>
    if let cardArray: AnyObject = plistDict["array"]{
        var names = cardArray.filter {$0["Class"] == 1} .map {$0["name"]!}
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you explain what does "not working" actually mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bit of pain with all the casts, I tested this with a dummy object.

the argument of `contentsOfFile` must be `path` not `"/path"`

```
if let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("CardList", ofType: "plist") {
  let plistDict = NSDictionary(contentsOfFile: path) as! Dictionary<String,AnyObject>
  if let cardArray = plistDict["array"] as? [AnyObject] {
    let names = cardArray.filter {$0["Class"] as! Int == 1}.map {$0["name"] as! String}
    println(names)
  }
}
```

Edit:

if you would create the plist file only with String values (you can later convert the string `toInt()`, then there's less casting

```
…
   if let cardArray = plistDict["array"] as? Array<[String:String]> {
     let names = cardArray.filter {$0["Class"]! == "1"}.map {$0["name"]!}
   }
```

Comment: Thanks vadian!! I knew you'd know! I am still learning swift so all these typecasts are a pain. I really appreciate all your knowledge with this stuff!

Comment: The only issue I am getting with this code is that it is unexpectedly finding nil.

Comment: insert `println()` lines to find out where, actually could only occur in lines 2 and 4

Comment: Good idea. I don't know why I am not thinking to do these things yet. Self teaching yourself these programming languages is fun :P.

Comment: The unexpected find nil error occurs in the actual filter line and not before. When I print out just the array everything works fine. It seems as though it may be having a hard time with recognizing the int? I may try converting the whole database over to strings but that will probably take a good amount of time as i have over 586 objects.

Comment: look thru your plist. There are probably one ore more `Class` properties which are not `Integer`. Change the filter line to `cardArray.filter {!($0["Class"] is Int)}` and `println()` the result. It will contain all dictionaries with a non-Int `Class` property

Comment: Beautiful! The filter worked great pointed me right to the error which wasn't it not being a int but rather a misspelling of the Class. I accidentally spelled it as CLass. With these filters I should be able to present the data I want now that I understand exactly how they work with plist. I appreciate all your help with this! If I could double check your answer to give you an extra point I would!

Answer (score 0):

In this line of code:

```
if let cardArray: AnyObject = plistDict["array"] {
```

you are storing the content of `plistDict["array"]` into a variable of `AnyObject` type. But `AnyObject` is not an array, although the instance it points to can actually be an array.

You should attempt a downcast to an array - if for example it should be an array of strings:

```
if let cardArray = plistDict["array"] as? [String] {
    ...
}
```

Comment: I'll give this a try thanks I'll keep you updated if this solves my issue or leads me down the path i need to go.